# How can I have multiple authors for one post in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I have the following header on a jekyll post with a single author "usman" which generates the [this](http://www.techtraits.com/System%20Admin/2013/02/24/The-problems-of-working-in-App-engine/) article.  I would like to have something like "authors: usman, someone_else" so a colleague can also contribute to the article. Is this possible? How would I set it up.

```
--- 
layout: post
title: The pitfalls of building services using Google App Engine -- Part I
date: 2013-02-24 08:18:17
author: usman
categories: 
- System Admin
tags:
- GAE

---
```

I took a look at the post template for the theme I am using and it has the following line:

```
{% assign author = site.authors[page.author] %}
```

This will obviously only support one author, Is there a way to get both authors of the page? i.e. page.author[0] for example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to specify multiple authors in your YAML Frontmatter, then you are going to want to use YAML's list syntax like you did with categories and tags, like this:

```
author:
- usman
- someone_else
```

This will be useful for dynamically injecting author information into each of the posts.

As for allowing multiple people to contribute to the same article, I don't think this has anything to do with Jekyll or what is specified in the Frontmatter. This is an issue of having your Jekyll content hosted in a shared place (such as on GitHub, like many do) where both you and your collaborator can both work on the file. That being said, be aware that you may run into nasty merge conflicts if you work on that same markdown file in parallel.

**Update**

This is an update based on the OP's edits to the original question.

A simple hacked approach would be to set your author tag like this:

```
author: Usman and Someone_Else
```

This doesn't give you much flexibility though. A better solution, which would require you to modify the template you are using, would be to do something like the following:

First, setup your YAML Front Matter so that it can support multiple authors.

```
authors:
- Usman
- Someone_else
```

Now, you modify the template to go through the authors specified in the YAML Front Matter.

```
<p>
{% assign authorCount = page.authors | size %}
{% if authorCount == 0 %}
    No author
{% elsif authorCount == 1 %}
    {{ page.authors | first }}
{% else %}
    {% for author in page.authors %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            {{ author }}
        {% elsif forloop.last %}
            and {{ author }}
        {% else %}
            , {{ author }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</p>
```

Resulting HTML:

If no authors are specified:

```
<p>No author</p>
```

If one author is specified:

```
<p>Usman</p>
```

If two authors are specified:

```
<p>Usman and Someone_Else</p>
```

If more than two authors are specified:

```
<p>Usman, Bob, and Someone_Else</p>
```

Comment: Thx, my question was around syntax I already have this in git for collaboration. This does not generate the the author html properly. See updated question

Comment: @UsmanIsmail Does my updated answer better address your question now?

Comment: Yes, so what I was missing was that its the theme that contains the html template. thx

Comment: The comma before the "and" in the more than two authors example would not actually be printed the way it is written now.