# How to specify multiple authors for a single post, then count the posts each author is related to?

Tags: arrays, jekyll, liquid

## What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to create a list for the posts *each author* has written. This is a problem since *each post* should be able to specify multiple authors.

Let's say we have 3 posts in total and 3 authors in total.

**Edit 1:** as suggested in the answers this is best done by listing the authors in a front matter list instead of a CSV string. So,

Like this

**Post:**

```
---
title: post
authors:
  - foo
  - bar
---
```

instead of like this:

**Post:**

```
---
title: post
authors: [foo, bar]
---
```

#### Problem setup:

(edited, according to **Edit 1**)

**Post 1:**

```
---
title: post1
authors:
  - foo
  - bar
---
```

**Post 2:**

```
---
title: post2
authors:
  - foo
  - bar
---
```

**Post 3:**

```
---
title: post3
authors:
  - john doe
  - bar
---
```

**Out:**

```
bar (3) 
john doe (1)
foo (2)
```

A click on the author should then result in all posts getting displayed.

Alternatively an array can be displayed like this, but it's not helping the case, just an equivalent style.

### What I tried

I did the same with categories and tags and [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21080786/5476399) worked like a charm. However, replacing `site.categories` with `site.authors` is somehow not supported.

returns:

> Liquid Exception: 0 is not a symbol nor a string in authors.html

I suppose this is due to the nature of `categories` and `tags` being arrays by default.
I think it would help to be able to set the front matter tag `authors` as an array somehow. I suppose this is done in _config.yml, but I busted by head in with it.

As of now I got as far as coming up with a way to target individual authors in an array, but I'm far from being able to list them individually and counting them up. I suppose I'm limited due to the nature of authors not being an array by default, otherwise implementations like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945944/jekyll-liquid-output-category-list-with-post-count) would work with custom front matter variables like `authors`, but they don't.

**What I meant (when I said "As of now"):**

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    <li><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ author.url }}">{{ post.authors }}</a> ({{ post.authors[0] }})</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Out:**

```
foobar (foo)
foobar (foo)
john doebar (john doe)
```

Afterall, I think I'm missing something here. I'm probably not the first one who tried this but the only documentation I found was from people who attempted what I'm trying but didn't really get there.

[This user for example created a way to count users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189008/how-can-i-have-multiple-authors-for-one-post-in-jekyll), but when used with `site.authors`

it returns the `array size == 0`-*if clause*:

> No author

It seems like a simple thing, but for some reason isn't. At least for me.

**Edit 2:**

based on Kieths answer I came closer to getting there, but I have issues with creating an emphty array. According to this issue in Jekyll this seems to be a [problem in general](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3246). However a workaround seems to be to assign a variable and [split it with an emphty tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41266780/5476399).
Currently I struggle with adding authors to the array so I can assess it's size.

```
{% assign authors = site.posts | map: 'authors' | uniq %}
{% assign authorCount = '' | split: '' %}

  <div class="softwaretitle">
    {% for author in authors %}
      <a>{{ author }}</a>


      {% for post in site.posts %}
        {% for post_author in post.authors %}
          {% if post_author == author %}

            {% assign authorCount = authorCount | push author %}
            <a>({{ page.authorCount | size }})</a>

          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %Edit 2:}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

**Out:**

> Error: Liquid error (.../_includes/authors.html line 14): wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) included 
>                Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.

**Line 14:**

```
{% assign authorCount = authorCount | push author %}
```

**Edit 3:**

**At last, the final result (without link to the post list, but thats details)**

```
<!-- Get a list of unique authors -->
  {% assign authors = site.posts | map: 'authors' | uniq | sort%}
  {% assign author_post_count = 0 %}
  {% for author in authors %}
          {% assign author_post_count = 0 %}

    <div class="">
      <li><a>{{ author }}
      {% for post in site.posts %}

        {% for post_author in post.authors %}
          {% if post_author == author %}
          {% assign author_post_count = author_post_count | | plus: 1 %}

          {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      <span>&nbsp ({{ author_post_count }})</span></a></li>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Out:**

```
bar (3) 
john doe (1)
foo (2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

To get a list of authors (without duplicates) and including the total number of posts the author has contributed to, together with a list of posts' titles and a link to the posts.

```
  {% assign authors = site.posts | map: 'authors' | uniq %}

  {% for author in authors %}
  {% assign author_post_count = 0 %}
   {% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.authors %}
     {% for post_author in post.authors %}
      {% if post_author == author %}
        {% assign author_post_count = author_post_count | plus: 1 %}
      {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
      <h2>{{ author }} - {{ author_post_count }}</h2>
      {% for post in site.posts %}
       {% if post.authors %}
        {% for post_author in post.authors %}
          {% if post_author == author %}
           {% assign author_url_query =  author | replace: ' ', '-' %}
            <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="A posts {{ author }}">
             {{ post.title }}
            </a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

If instead, you want to have a page per author that includes a list of posts written by them (automatically generated), you will need to extend Jekyll through a custom plugin. This is very possible if you have experience with the Ruby programming language. This is a very close example: https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen and you can simply remove the `_config` data requirements and hardcode the directory names and permalinks :)

Comment: Thank you for answering this question in such detail. However, as is, the code lists the authors and appends the projects names (post.title) for each involvement in a post. However, what I'd had liked is a way count the projects and on click return a list of the project names in the format of "author (3)" if the unique author was involved in 3 posts. Meaning, it's very close to meeting the criteria of the task.

Comment: I edited the question in accordance to your suggestion with the front matter lists. Works a lot better.

Comment: Sorry... a wee bit busy :) Is your current issue just to get the total number of posts by author? Answer updated in case that's what you need! :)

Comment: You helped me a ton! Thanks! I Edited the final result in my answer.

Comment: if you want, include Edit 3 in your answer, so people don't get confused. I'll delete edit 3 then.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem :

- on a post : print author(s) + number of posts written and link to the authors page
- on an author's page : print author's datas + list written posts

### Solution

We already have posts that are described like this :

```
---
title: post2
authors: [foo, bar]

# or with the alternate YAML array syntax
authors:
  - foo
  - bar

---
```

For authors, we can user a specific collection that will automatically generate author's page.

In `_config.yml` :

```
collections:
  authors:
    output: true

defaults:
  - scope:
      type: authors
    values:
      layout: authors
```

An author's page can be described like this :

**_authors/foo.md**

```
---
uid : foo
firstname: John
lastname: Foo
---

Some bio here ...
```

**Posts List (index or any page):**

```
{% assign posts = site.posts %}
{% comment %}
or {% assign posts = paginator.posts %} if you use pagination
{% endcomment %}

<ul>
{% for post in posts %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a>
    <br>{% include authors.html post=post %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

We will also use our authors include in **_layouts/post.html**

```
...
    <h1 class="post-title" itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
    <p>{% include authors.html post=page %}</p>
...
```

Now the magic : **_includes/authors.html**

```
{% assign post = include.post %}

{% comment %}## if we have a least one author in post authors array {% endcomment %}
{% if post.authors and post.authors != empty %}

  {% comment %} ## We will build a string for each author,
                   store it in authorsArray
                   then reassemble it at the end {% endcomment %}
  {% assign authorsArray = "" | split: "" %}

  {% for author in post.authors %}

    {% comment %}## Count posts for current author {% endcomment %}
    {% assign authorsPostsCount = site.posts | where_exp: "post", "post.authors contains author" | size %}

    {% comment %}## Get authors data based on uid matching in the collection {% endcomment %}
    {% assign authorsDatas = site.authors | where: "uid", author | first %}

    {% if authorsDatas %}
      {% capture authorString %}
      <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ authorsDatas.url }}">{{ authorsDatas.firstname }} {{ authorsDatas.lastname }} ({{ authorsPostsCount }}) </a>
      {% endcapture %}

    {% else %}
      {% comment %}## No entry for this author in the collection
                   ## or author spelling is wrong {% endcomment %}
      {% capture authorString %}
        {{ author | capitalize }} ({{ authorsPostsCount }})
      {% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}

    {% comment %}## Push result in authorsArray {% endcomment %}
    {% assign authorsArray = authorsArray | push: authorString %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% comment %}## Create a sentence with array elements {% endcomment %}
  by {{ authorsArray | array_to_sentence_string }}
{% endif %}
```

**_layouts/author.html**

```
---
layout: default
---

<h1>{{ page.firstname }} - {{ page. lastname }}</h1>

{% assign authorsPosts = site.posts | where_exp: "post", "post.authors contains page.uid" %}

<ul>
  {% for p in authorsPosts %}
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: while a great reference, that i'll be able to use further into the project, I don't really need a dedicated authors page since I don't store meta data about the authors. Thank you however for the effort you made with this answer. I would appreciate  a few more comments to each code block.